# I am looking for some simple PHP code to send Twilio SMS message (without a framework required)

Tags: php, twilio, sms

OK, I know I am a noob but I have gotten by with PHP for a while by just writing code in a text editor. With Twilio samples everything is prefaced with...

```
// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

like they show here..
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages

do I need this framework?  I just want to send a single SMS message (or maybe loop through a bunch)

Comment: apparently, usage [without composer](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php-manual-install), although I'd strongly recommend trying to wrap your head around using Composer (package and dependency management.) it'll come in handy on many occasions.

Comment: You don't _need_ the twilio PHP library, because you could write all the code to generate the necessary HTTP requests to twilio's servers yourself instead. But using the library should remove a lot of the potential complexity and pitfalls, and make it much easier to use the functionality you need without writing and testing a lot of code. In general, try to avoid re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: (If you're actually asking whether you need Composer, then, no you could just download all the library files (and any other libraries it depends on) manually and place them in a folder, and then change the require_once path accordingly. Composer just makes that process more automatic. So again you don't _need_ it, it's just meant to be there to make your life easier. Another thing that would make your life a lot easier is using a proper IDE instead of a text editor. You needn't pay for one necessarily - there are several free ones which support PHP).

Answer (score 4):

Something to get you started. Replace the ***`...`*** things.

```php
<?php

$twilio_account_sid = "AC...";
$twilio_auth_token = "2d...";
$twilio_phone_number = "+1...";

$payload = [
    'From' => $twilio_phone_number,
    'To' => '+1...',
    'Body' => 'This is the body of the message'
];

$url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' . $twilio_account_sid . '/Messages.json';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $twilio_account_sid . ':' . $twilio_auth_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump( $status );
var_dump( $response );

?>
```

Comment: Yes!!  Also had an old version of PHP so the [] for arrays didn't work  Big thanks Alex.